# Messaging endpoint of a Microsoft framework BOT

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

Does the messaging endpoint of bot need to be anonymous?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bot Framework works with bots deployed on any cloud hosting service or server, as long as you have an internet-accessible endpoint and a valid SSL certificate. Refer to
https://blog.botframework.com/2020/11/23/bots-secured-behind-a-firewall-teams/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=bots-secured-behind-a-firewall-teams and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-security?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#which-specific-urls-do-i-need-to-allow-list-in-my-corporate-firewall-to-access-bot-framework-services for more details

Comment: Thanks for your response @ranusharao . I have gone through the documents but I couldn’t find answer to my specific question 1) above - **Does the messaging endpoint of bot need to be anonymous?**  – would be great if you can shine some light on this.

Comment: your bot can be hosted anywhere on the Internet. On your own servers, in Azure, or in any other data center. The only requirement is that the bot must expose a publicly-accessible HTTPS endpoint

Comment: Thank you @Mamatha-MSFT I understand that BOT can be hosted anywhere. I am specifically interested in knowing that if the messaging endpoint of bot which is used in  BOT registration in azure need to be anonymous or can we protect it with any auth e.g. Oauth, API Key etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bot framework v4 SDK and when you register a bot in the Azure portal, for example via the Bot Channels Registration, this authentication automatically performed. So, you don't need to explicitly write any code. If you want to restrict the use of bot to users belonging to your tenant you can add authentication to a bot using OAuth. Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that requests to your /api/messages endpoint include a JWT bearer token issued by the bot framework. The SDK will check this for you.

This appears to be the code where it performs the validation:

https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/fc5dcc535855cf453b0ebf373121277d824ff840/libraries/botbuilder/src/botFrameworkAdapter.ts#L1180

If you're implementing without the SDK, then you will need to do the JWT verification.